# Python: If Code Block within a for codeblock

Tags: python

I recently took a python course and am now trying to supplement and expand my knowledge by practice.

I am writing a program that enters various data attributes into a file.

I've observed something though, and that is I have a for loop that will allow me to enter various attributes about the team member in question and then add it to the file. However, I'm finding that the code is not 'blocking' out as I'm used to it doing. I went and checked the code above, and when I trying adding the code block *above* the for block,  it adds it. Does anyone know whether or not you can add an IF block to a "for" block? If not, can someone describe to me what properties of  a statement like that violate the conventions of python?

Please review the code below for insight. This is my second question on stackoverflow, so I'll do my best to emphasize the code in question.

```
#This is a program that gets information about team members and
#returns whether or not they are any good.

def main():
    #Get the name of the user:
    user = str(input('What is your name user?: ')
    #Get the number of team members
    num_team = int(input('How many team member records ' + \
                         'do you want to create {}'.format(name)))

    team_name = str(input('what is the name of the team' + \
                          'that you are entering members for {}'.format(name)))
    team_name = team_name + '.txt'
    #we are now going to create a file that is name after the team
    #team that we are inputting team members for

    if offense_defense == "O":


    team_file = open(team_name,'w')

    #Get each team members data and write it to the file.
    for count in (1, num_team + 1):
               print('{} Enter data for team member #'.format(name), count, sep='')
               name = input('Name: ')
               offense_defense = input('Is {} a member of the Offense (O) or the Defense (D)')
               **if offense_defense == 'O':**


               passes = input('Enter the number of passes: ')
               dept = input(': ')
```

Comment: The `**` are just there for the question right? not actually in your code?

Comment: You cannot have an `if` (or any other statement that ends with a colon, that introduces a new block) without an indented block underneath it.  The `pass` statement exist for the specific purpose of providing such a block when you don't have anything else to write at the moment.

Comment: You can have an if statement in a for loop.  Is it intentional for you to have no code being executed after your if statement?  As jason says, it must be indented.  Indentation is how python recognizes flow of control.